# Stripe checkout - trigger event when payment submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

How do you trigger a javascript event when a user submits a Stripe Checkout modal?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076287/event-or-methods-for-the-stripe-checkout-modal) was some help but it seems like it's talking about any close event (not just submission), and I'm only worried about submission. Also, it seems a bit old.

Comment: that would be the token callback https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Comment: doesn't that just send the user details to Stripe?

Comment: the token callback is what is called when the submission to stripe has completed and you are given the token

Answer (score 0):

I used the Same , As Mathew mention it is getting a token.

```
 onToken = (token) => {

        axios.post('/api/charge',
                {
                    token: token,
                    comapnyName: this.state.auth.companyName,
                    email: this.state.auth.email,
                }
            ).then(data=>{
```

when you use the token={this.token}
it will trigger this method but keep in mind, at the back end you have to use

```
 stripe.charges.create({
                amount: 2000,
                currency: 'usd',
                card: token.id,

        }).then(
```

hope this will be helpful to someone